# mysql replication - get master server past records on slave server

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-workbench, database-replication, mysql-5.6

I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I have 2 mysql servers.

1) Master server

2) Slave server

Now i configure them for replication. After configuration the records which i add in master server are successfully replicated on slave server. But i also need those records which are already in master server (before replication setup) to be replicate in slave server (after replication setup). Now how can i replicate those past records from master server to slave server?

Answer (score 2):

Replication doesn't support this.

Standard procedure is to start replication on the master, note the replication position somewhere, take a db dump, import it into the slave, and enable replication from the previously noted position.

`mysqldump` has a flag to automatically configure the slave's replication position in the dump file.